# NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Tabs(dirty, state: _TabsState#fefcf): The method '[]' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-html

I have read similar answers for this type of error but still, I am not able to resolve it in my code.

When I tap the button it shows an error screen for some time and then displays loader which should be displayed while the data is being fetched.

[error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkA19.jpg)

[loading screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJkdp.jpg)

[final screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt9Zh.jpg)

here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Dictionary.dart';
import 'Services.dart';

class NewTab extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewTabState createState() => _NewTabState();
}

class _NewTabState extends State<NewTab> {
  List<Dictionary> _users;
  int len;
 @override
 void initState() { 
   super.initState();
    Services.getUsers().then((users) {
      setState(() {
        _users = users;
        len = users.length - 1 ; 
      });
    });
 }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     Dictionary user = _users[len];
    print(user);
     return FutureBuilder(
                future: Services.getUsers(),
                builder: (context,AsyncSnapshot<List<Dictionary>> snapshot){
                  if(snapshot.data==null){
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  }else{
                        return  DefaultTabController(length: 2, 
                        child:Scaffold(
                          appBar: AppBar(
                            title : Text('Meaning',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: "Pangolin",
                                fontSize: 35,
                              )
                            ),
                            centerTitle: true,
                            bottom: TabBar(
                                  tabs: <Widget>[
                                    Tab(text:'Meaning',
                                        icon: Icon(Icons.book_outlined),
                                        ),
                                    Tab(text:'Example',
                                        icon: Icon(Icons.directions_transit)
                                        ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                          ),
                          
                          body : TabBarView(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    child: Container(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                    child: ListView.builder(
                                      itemCount: user.meanings.length,
                                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                        print(index);
                                        List<Meaning> mean = user.meanings;
                                        return ListTile(
                                          title: Text(mean[index].definitions[0].definition
                                          , style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        );
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),),Container(
                child: Text('home'),
              ),]
              )
                        )
                        );
                  }
       }, 
     );
  }
}
```

code for onpressed function in raised button

```
onPressed: ()=>{ 
           Navigator.of(context).push(
                new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => NewTab())
            )
            },
```

code for services.dart

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'Dictionary.dart';
import 'package:dictionary_app/home.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class Services {
  
  static final  url = 'https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en_US/$word';
 
  static Future<List<Dictionary>> getUsers() async {
      
    try {
      print(url);
      final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      print(response.statusCode);
      if (200 == response.statusCode) {
         final List<Dictionary> users = dictionaryFromJson(response.body);
        return users;
      } 
      else {
        return <Dictionary>[];
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return <Dictionary>[];
    }
  }
}
```

error:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building NewTab(dirty, state: _NewTabState#1662b):
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: [](null)

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  NewTab file:///E:/Flutter-Projects/flutter3/dictionary_app/lib/home.dart:120:74

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:63:5)
#1      _NewTabState.build (package:dictionary_app/newtab.dart:25:30)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4749:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4632:15)
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:11)
#5      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4322:5)
#6      ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4610:5)
#7      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4796:11)
#8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4605:5)
...     Normal element mounting (166 frames)
#174    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3662:14)
#175    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6285:36)
#176    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3414:18)
#177    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5717:32)
#178    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6308:17)
#179    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3401:15)
#180    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4657:16)
#181    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:11)
#182    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4322:5)
#183    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4837:5)
#184    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3401:15)
#185    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4657:16)
#186    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4322:5)
#187    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4985:5)
#188    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3401:15)
#189    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4657:16)
#190    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4322:5)
#191    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4985:5)
#192    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:181:11)
#193    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3401:15)
#194    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6154:14)
#195    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3401:15)
#196    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4657:16)
#197    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:11)
#198    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4322:5)
#199    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4837:5)
#200    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3401:15)
#201    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6154:14)
#202    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3401:15)
#203    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6154:14)
#204    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3401:15)
#205    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4657:16)
#206    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4322:5)
#207    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4985:5)
#208    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3401:15)
#209    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4657:16)
#210    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4805:11)
#211    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4322:5)
#212    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2619:33)
#213    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:878:21)
#214    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:328:5)
#215    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1147:15)
#216    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1084:9)
#217    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1000:5)
#221    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:163:10)
#222    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:259:5)
#223    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:126:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can remove your `initState` method since you are already using the `FutureBuilder` to fetch your `Services.getUsers()`.

Now, you have defined your variables like this,

```
List<Dictionary> _users;
int len;
```

But both of them are `null` when `build` method is going to be called for the first time.

So inside your build method, you can't directly use,

```
Dictionary user = _users[len];
print(user);
```

Since, `_users` is null when `build` is called for the first time. So remove those 2 lines.

Now, rest of your code is correct, except for one part,

Inside your `else` case of `if(snapshot.data==null)`, define your `user` variable like this,

```
else {
  Dictionary user = snapshot.data!.last; // This gives you the last element of the array
```

Now, your code should work.
Here is the [paste bin link](https://pastebin.com/LRm8Ad29) for the full code of `_NewTabState`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to initialize your list

```
List<Dictionary> _users = [];
```

It’s better way:

```
snapShot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting ? :
```